# Python and Node Js (what to do if the client doesn't have python)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, npm

I am trying to make a desktop application with NodeJs (electron) and I want to be able to also implement python scripts using Child Process in Node, but I would like to know what I can do to control when a user does not have Python installed on their machine. Any way to install python to the client without having to do it manually, or if you have a different version installed do not have conflicts; or to compile the .py so that Python is not needed?

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const process = spawn("python", ["fileController.py"]);

process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

process.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

process.on("close", (code) => {
console.log(`Exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do it, make a script that check out does the system has all the dependencies including python environment. I can attach a sample piece of code which might help you to achieve it:

```
const pyVersion = (cb) => {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn('python1', ['-V']);
    spawn.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
        return cb(err, null);
    });

    spawn.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        cb(null, data.toString());
    });
}

pyVersion((err,version) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error is ${err}`);
        // ask user to download it or anything
    }
    else {
        console.log(`Version is ${version}`);
        // run the script, you might check the specific version exists or not
    }
})
```

Run this code before spawning the python process.